# How to make Razor not display special characters as html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

The page I'm working on displays content from a database in readonly input box. My problem is that it's displaying any special characters as the html code (ie: & displays as &). How do you get the code to display properly?

I'm using QuerySingle to connect to the database, don't know if that makes a difference. I'm new to using Razor. Any help is much appreciated.

Code in question:

```
var queryloan = "SELECT * FROM loans WHERE LoanId = @0";
var queryloandata = db.QuerySingle(queryloan, queryformstatus_submitted.doc_loanid);
<form class="jotform-form" action="submit-form.cshtml?isadmin=@(isadmin)&loanid=@(loanid)" method="post" name="form_30905105572145" id="30905105572145" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="30905105572145" />
<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" value="@doc_id" />
<div class="form-all">
    <ul class="form-section">
        <li id="cid_3" class="form-input-wide">
            <div class="form-header-group">
                <h2 id="header_3" class="form-header">
                    Borrower Sources & Uses Summary
                </h2>
                    @if (queryformstatus_submitted.doc_approval == "Pending Approval" || queryformstatus_submitted.doc_approval == "Approved")
                    {
                        <text><br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="error">
                            This form has already been submitted and cannot be edited. It is for reference only.</div></text>
                    }
                    @if(userid != queryformstatus_submitted.doc_userid){
                    <text><br/><br/><div class="error">You may not edit this form. It is for reference only.</div></text>
              }

            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-line" id="id_4">
            <label class="form-label-left" id="label_4" for="input_4">
                1. Property Name: 
            </label>
            <div id="cid_4" class="form-input">

            <input type="text" class=" form-textbox" id="input_4" name="q4_1Property" size="40" value="@Helpers.checkEmptyPreFill(queryinputvalue,"q4_1Property",queryloandata.LoanName)"/>
            </div>
        </li>
```

I'm not sure but I believe it may be something in this helper function that's causing the html code:

```
@helper checkEmptyPreFill(IEnumerable<dynamic> queryinputvalue, string field_id, string defaultval, int cloned = 0) {  

var reqValue = queryinputvalue.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field_name.Equals(field_id));
var return_value = "";
if(reqValue != null){
    return_value = reqValue.field_data;
} else {
    return_value = defaultval;
}

if(cloned == 1){
    return_value = "";
}

@return_value
```

}

Comment: I assume you want to display & amp; as &.  Have you tried using [HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I have tried HtmlDecode. I have tried it around variable in the input value (ie: WebUtility.HtmlDecode(queryloandata.LoanName)) but it doesn't do anything. Is there something I'm missing? Am I just trying to Decode it in the wrong spot?

Comment: I got it to work like this `<input type="text" readonly value="@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlEncodedString)" />` where `var htmlEncodedString = "Tom &amp; Jerry";`

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I tried it the way you described but it's still coming up as &amp;. Maybe because the variable is changing it's value based on what it's pulling from the database? Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm afraid.  Perhaps you could update your question to provide a bit more information about the "queryloandata" object and its LoanName property, maybe with an example value.  It would also be good if you could show the code for your form from your .cshtml view file.

Comment: I've updated the post with more of the pages code. I think things may be getting muddled up in the helper function but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The razor helper returns a `HelperResult` object so you'll have to convert it to a string before you can call `HtmlDecode` on it.  Replace:

```
@Helpers.checkEmptyPreFill(queryinputvalue,"q4_1Property",queryloandata.LoanName)
```

with the following:

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Helpers.checkEmptyPreFill(queryinputvalue,"q4_1Property",queryloandata.LoanName).ToString())
```

I would also suggest that you move some of the logic and data access code out of your view and into a controller but this should give you the result that you'e after.